# python exchangelib item output

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, exchangelib

I can't figure out how to get only the first item from a <strike>list</strike> loop.

I am trying to get the first/next calendar item from exchangelib:

My code:

```
(...)

x = 5000 # minutes in future to look for calendar items

calendar = art(
    start=time,
    end=time + timedelta (minutes = x), 
)

for item in calendar:
    print(item.subject)
```

Output:
All the calendar items in this period of time. What do I need to change in the last two lines of code if I want to get only the first/ next item?

Example Output:

```
First Line
Second Line
Third Line
```

Wanted Output:

```
First Line
```

Edit: Gained some more knowledge in the last few months, i can answer my own question now. And its very simple, I probably wrongly expressed myself and people misunderstood.

Solution:

```
for item in calendar:
    print(item.subject)
    break # a simple break so the loop only returns the first result
```

Comment: Do you mean ["X1" "Y1" ....] as you final output you want in 1 list ?

Comment: what are the input and the desired output? What is `item.subject`? Your post is confusing since you ask for `["X1" "X2"...]`, and you get that during the first split. So, what is exactly the issue?

Comment: The input are multiple calendar items coming from exchangelib, I need only the first one from all the items. My problem is that with my code I am only getting the first word from every line instead of just the first line

Comment: What is "item", and what is "xyz" ???

Comment: "item" is a calendar item coming from exchangelib
"xyz" is a defined period of time in which the script is looking for calendar items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just modify and use your code, here is how you can get all the first values in 1 single list.

```
test = []
for item in xyz:            
    item_split=item.subject.split()
    test.append(item_split[0])
print(test)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i got the following error: TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Sorry @Biorez. Typo with variable name. Fixed it now. Should work.

Comment: This got really close to the final solution! Added solution to my code above.

Comment: Great to hear it helped. Please upvote if you like. :)

Comment: Just noticed one (hopefully small) mistake: I am not getting the first item, i am getting the last item... any idea?

Comment: Yes. In your solution I see you have written `list.append(p)` outside the `for loop`. Put that line inside the loop and you will get all the values. Also, I think you might have to change `pass` with `continue`.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! 
Now I am getting all the items again... maybe an [0] array somewhere?

Comment: I cannto write another answer its closed. You also need to include the 2 lines in my answer inside `for` loop after you have checked for `None` and written `continue`. Change the variable name from `list` to `test` in your solution. Never use keywords as your variable name. `list` is used for `LISTS` in Python.

Comment: I have edited your solution in the question post. have a look at it. That should work fine.

Comment: Now I'm getting the first word of every item in the list.. close shot

Comment: Great I could be of help. :) Cheers

Comment: Thanks so far! But thats not the whole solution yet.. I am getting the **first** word of **every line** now, but I need to get only the first line..

Example:
`item.subject=[first test, second test, third test]`
With your code the output is: 
`first
second
third`

But i need: `First test`

Comment: The output you are getting is what I was trying to solve as I did not have the sample input. Now, to get `first test` as your output why can't you just access the first element of the list with `item.subject[0]` as `item.subject` is a list as I can see.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvinience..
item.subject[0] outputs just the first letter of every line 
Output:
`f  #(first)
s #(second) 
t #(third)`

item.subject[3] for example, outputs the fourth letter of every line  
Output:
`s
o
r`

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension one-liner: `items = [item.subject.split()[0] for item in xyz]`.

Which amounts to:

```
items = []
for item in xyz:
    items.append(item.subject.split()[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, you want to split ONLY the first item on your list. Then you should simply access ONLY the first item (`xyz[0]`) and then split it. There is no need to iterate over the list.

```
print(xyz[0].subject.split())
```

Comment: Well that did something...
I don't want to split only the first line, i figured out i need to use split to only **show** the first line and "split" the rest of it away.

What your code did is just overwriting every item i get into the first one.

So lets say I'm getting 3 items:
X1 X2 X3
Y1 Y2 Y3
and
Z1 Z2 Z3

with your code im getting

X1 X2 X3
X1 X2 X3
X1 X2 X3
which is something

Comment: Please clarify your question adding an example of the input. It's fundamental to answer properly.

Comment: Added more code

Answer (score 0):

You are already getting ["X1", "X2", "X3", ...] and so on in your first step. You can do `print(test[:1]` in the first step only. Or you can also do `xyz[0].subject.split()`. This will not require any loops.